# Poor FPS while playing Trove

Tags: trove

I have been experiencing low FPS while playing Trove. I have all graphics set quite low and I have even set the priority higher in control panel but so far I have only had up to around 27 FPS. Also, I have set the renderer to OpenGL because my FPS is better using this rather than DirectX.

My PC specs:
Windows 7 Pro (64-bit), 
Zotac GeForce GT 9500, 
intel Core 2 Quad, 
8 GB RAM.

Comment: It looks like you have the minimum system requirements to run the game, although you don't list your hard drive space.  Have you tried playing right after a reboot?  That might clean out a few things.

Comment: I think the view/render distance is one of the heaviest settings. Try putting that even lower?

Comment: My hard drive space is 751GB on both drives (C: and E:) and I have tried turning the games settings down further but I am still only getting 20-30 fps. Thanks Frank, I didn't check the minimum system requirements and I have only got the lowest ones so I might get a PC upgrade soon. Does anyone know where I can get a cheap-ish, but great gaming PC that would run games like CS:GO, Minecraft, Trove etc? (I am in GBP £)

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at the [support forums](https://support.trionworlds.com/hc/en-us/articles/203372558-Trove-Minimum-System-Requirements) of Trove:

```
Windows Vista, 7, 8
At least 2 GB System RAM
Intel HD Graphics 3000 (integrated) or better
Broadband internet connection or better
At least 1 GB free hard drive space
```

The graphic card you are trying to use is at least [7 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_9_series#Technical_Summary_of_Desktop_G9x_GPUs), technically speaking.

Also, on [this wiki](http://trove.gamepedia.com/Trove_Wiki:Game_FAQ?cookieSetup=true#What_are_the_system_requirements_to_play_Trove.3F) you can check that an OpenGL3-enabled card is a "community" suggested spec. Unfortunately, your card supports only OpenGL2.1(spec [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9600-gt/specifications)).

Other things like disk type(hdd, ssd) and bus(sata, ide) and your processor should create a bottleneck on your gaming experience.

**tl;dr**, A hardware upgrade will be necessary to increase your overall performance :( .